# Importing CSV to mySQL (xampp)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, xampp, import-csv

So I wanted to import a CSV to make a new table, and while it's successful, I had 2 issues.
First is, while it says drag and drop works, mine doesn't, it shows an icon which means wrong format. However browsing the storage works normally.

Second is making the first row the column names. Even though I ticked the checkbox which function is for that, while it did set the column names, it still used the first row as the part of the data too. So the first row of the created table contains the names.

Why is that?

Here's the screenshot of the drag and drop failure.

[image: 1]

Comment: idk but both issues sound like bugs in Xampp, I don't think stackoverflow is the best place to ask about specific features in software/apps. Maybe try superuser.com or better yet just ask on their forum here https://community.apachefriends.org/

Comment: well I've downloaded a newer version of xampp and the taking first row as data is fixed, but still not the drag and drop... Yea I guess I'll ask there

Comment: "while it says drag and drop works" - what is "it"?